# Certificate Propagation Service CertPropSvc immediately stops

Tags: certificates, smartcard

Trying to use my smartcards, suddenly the certificates do not propagate. I try starting and restarting the Certificate Propagation Service, but it immediately stops.

An event is created in the Event Viewer "Application Error":

> Faulting application name: svchost.exe_CertPropSvc, version:
> 10.0.19041.1806, time stamp:  Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.19041.2130, time stamp:  Exception code: 0xc0000409
> Fault offset:  Faulting process id:  Faulting application start time:
> Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe Faulting
> module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll Report Id:  Faulting
> package full name:  Faulting package-relative application ID:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. Somehow, the Gemalto IDClassic V3 CAPI and KSP/CSP components are interfering and stopping the Certificate Propagation Service. If the minidriver is installed, instead, the problem is resolved.